# Unity changing friction from code not working (2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, unity3d-2dtools

I want to change a collider's physic's material from code, I use the code below. I see the material's friction changing in the inspector, however the collider behaves as if the friction wouldn't change.

```
 void checkOnGround() {
     Transform t;
     foreach(Collider2D c in collidingTiles) {
         t = c.transform;
         if(t.position.y - transform.position.y < -Misc.TILE_SIZE * 0.75f) {
             onGround = true;
             myCollider.sharedMaterial.friction = 0.8f;
             return;
         }
     }
     onGround = false;
     myCollider.sharedMaterial.friction = 0f;
     return;
 }
```

Comment: Why are you modifying sharedMaterial instead of material property?

Comment: there's no material property in 2D

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. When I tried using Unity's Physics2d, it was very rough and unpolished, so I switched back to 3d physics (even for 2d projects), and that's what I would recommend, in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are knowed Unity bug.
 You can disable/enable your collider to got the material changed applied, and a little flick texture sometimes.

Comment: funny thing this happens to in Box2D, long story short, the friction is cached at the start of the collision and is kept until the contact ends